# How to upload / download all format excel file to azure blob storage Nodejs server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload excel file to azure blob storage

```
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

// Enter your storage account name
const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME;

// Unique name for the container
const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;

// Azure AD Credential information is required to run this sample:
if (
  !process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID ||
  !process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID ||
  !process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET || !account || !containerName
) {
  return next(SystemResponse.badRequestError('Azure AD authentication information not provided, but it is required to run this sample. Exiting.'));
}

const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  defaultAzureCredential,
);



// Get a reference to a container
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

// Upload data to the blob
const blobName = `${req.files.file.name.split('.')[0]}+${new Date().getTime()}.${req.files.file.name.split('.')[1]}`;

// create blobClient for container
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

// upload file
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(`${containerName}${req.files.file.path}`, req.files.file.size);
```

i am using postman to upload excel file , but , only file path is stored in excel file not , actually content ,how can i solve this issue plz help ?
&& on downloading file name is coming in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2) and maybe you can use `parse-multipart` to receive your files:

**Install:**

```
npm install parse-multipart
```

**Code:**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    var multipart = require('parse-multipart');
    var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
    var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
    var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);

    // Enter your storage account name
    const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME;

    // Unique name for the container
    const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;

    // Azure AD Credential information is required to run this sample:
    if (
      !process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID ||
      !process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID ||
      !process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET || !account || !containerName
    ) {
      return next(SystemResponse.badRequestError('Azure AD authentication information not provided, but it is required to run this sample. Exiting.'));
    }

    const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      defaultAzureCredential,
    );



    // Get a reference to a container
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    // Upload data to the blob
    const blobName = `${parts[0].filename.split('.')[0]}+${new Date().getTime()}.${parts[0].filename.split('.')[1]}`;

    // create blobClient for container
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    // upload file
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(parts[0].data , parts[0].data.length);
};
```

Reason:

```
function upload(body: HttpRequestBody, contentLength: number, options?: BlockBlobUploadOptions)
```

The value of the [HttpRequestBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#upload_HttpRequestBody__number__BlockBlobUploadOptions_) should be `Blob, string, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView or a function which returns a new Readable stream whose offset is from data source beginning`, so you shouldn't use path.

================update=======================

According to the discussion, the file should be read according to the relative path, and the binary data of the file should be converted into a base64 string.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path'); 
//set relative path to file 
let relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(),${req.files.file.path}); 
//reading binary data of file 
let binaryData=fs.readFileSync(relativePath); 
//converting binary data to base64 string 
let base64String=Buffer.from(binaryData).toString("base64")
await blockBlobClient.upload(base64String, req.files.file.size);
```

================update2====================

```
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    // Upload data to the blob
    const blobName = `xxx.xlsx`;

    // create blobClient for container
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = blockBlobClient.downloadToFile("D:\\xxx\\xxx.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thanx for replying , but , i am trying to upload excel file ,  in request :-  req.files.file will give file to be uploaded ,i am using postman for selecting excel file ,   Please confirm , whether :- var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.files.file); will work here  or what i have pass so that file is uploaded on azure in correct format & download as it is ?

Comment: The parameter in `var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);` is the request body sent by your postman, which is in this [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJfcC.png). If you can, put the request body directly, according to my code there should be no problem.

Comment: If you don't want to use my code, could you please tell me which type of req is yours? I use `HttpRequest`.

Comment: In my case , i am using const multipart = require("connect-multiparty");
const multipartMiddleware = multipart();     this code gives :- req.files  when i select file in postman :- it gives all file details :-

Comment: {
  file: {
    fieldName: 'file',
    originalFilename: 'Productivity Manager - Task Tracking .xlsx',
    path: '/tmp/hFX6uhx6j50ubboYhmCHDxeS.xlsx',
    headers: {
      'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="Productivity Manager - Task Tracking .xlsx"',
      'content-type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    },
    size: 17619,
    name: 'Productivity Manager - Task Tracking .xlsx',
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  }
}

Comment: In postman , file format is not coming in req.body if i select by postman :- form-Data format is need to be chosen if i select file from postman,it comes in req.files not in req.body

Comment: Judging from the data you give, `req.files.file` does not get the content of the excel file, it only gets the metadata.

Comment: If you want to upload a file to storage, you must get the content of the file.

Comment: any package for getting data in correct format from excel sheet and store in req.body ? doing right now :- var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');    //set relative path to file
    let relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(),`${req.files.file.path}`);
    //reading binary data of file
    let binaryData=fs.readFileSync(relativePath);
    //converting binary data to base64 string
    let base64String=Buffer.from(binaryData).toString("base64")     ,  i have to pass base64String to  await blockBlobClient.upload(base64String, req.files.file.size);

Comment: If the solution I provided below works fine, could you please mark it as "accepted" ? This can be beneficial to other communities.

Comment: already accepted  , could you plz tell , how to download excel file in correct format ,i have only blob name

Comment: i am using :- const multipart = require('connect-multiparty'); package for  getting file like :-  req.files   , is there any package , where , we could use  import  inplace of require ?

Comment: @Hemendra Hi, Please [mark the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abanw.png) to end a question if the answer is solution, and then open a new question for another problem.:)

Comment: I updated the answer, this is the storage package, it is relatively simple, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs).

Comment: actually , i am not able to upload file in correct format to azure blob storage as yet , inside file  path is coming on downloading  ? any one can help , i am using postmans to select file &  using  // upload file
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(`${containerName}${req.files.file.path}`, req.files.file.size);